# Removing repeating or dulplicate characters from a string

Tags: java, duplicates

How can i remove the repeating character?
Like

> Umbrella should be Umbrela
>
> possible should be posible

```
public static String rem(String s,char c ){
    String result="";

    for (int i = 0; i+1 <s.length(); i++) {
        char a=s.charAt(i);
        char b=s.charAt(i+1);
        
        if(a!=c || b!=c){
            char d=a;
        IO.put(d+"\n");
    }
    
}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What language? What have you tried? What about different case? Do the characters have to be after each other (would "Eden" become "Edn")?

Comment: In Java. public static String rem(String s,char c ){
        String result="";

        for (int i = 0; i+1 <s.length(); i++) {
            char a=s.charAt(i);
            char b=s.charAt(i+1);
            
            if(a!=c || b!=c){
                char d=a;
            IO.put(d+"\n");
        }
        
    }
        return result;

Comment: Please edit that code into your question and state where you are stuck.

Comment: And Eden should remain Eden. it should remove one character form the consecutive characters like consecutive e in three, it should return thre.

Comment: in my code it is not returning the last character.

Comment: What about "accommodation" (where there are two different repeating letters)? Which of those letters do you provide as the `c` parameter?

Comment: `s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")` seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: it should be acomodation @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about how you would do it manually, using pen and paper?

1. Go through each character one by one from the left
2. If the current character is not same as the previous character, copy the character to the new string
3. Otherwise, skip the character and move to the next one.

Then, translating the above into code, would be something like this (assuming a non-null and non-empty input string):

```
    String input = "three";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    char lastChar = input.charAt(0); // get the first character
    output.append(lastChar); // store the first character in the output string

    // loop through the rest of the characters, starting from the second char
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        // add the current char to the output, if it is not same as the last char
        // in the output
        if (c != lastChar) {
            output.append(c);
            lastChar = c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

This can further easily be done using regular expressions once you've learned them (see Andy Turner's comment)

Comment: What if the first character of the string is `'0'`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I was being lazy :(, answer edited to use null char literal

Comment: Same problem: what if the first character of the string is `'\0'`?

Comment: What if you've got `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..."` in your string?

Comment: OK, but now you're repeatedly checking a condition which will never be true after the first iteration...

Comment: @AndyTurner better now?